# Visual Studio 2019 on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio

I am a linux user and for programming I use Visual Studio Code, the problem is that VS code is text editor not IDE so I cant open `.sln` files. Is there any way to install VS 2019 on any linux distro?

Comment: Try [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/)

Comment: Visual Studio only runs on Windows. You should be able to open .sln files in VSCode, though. [See this doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp#_roslyn-and-omnisharp) for example

Comment: but be aware of Rider: once you've used it for a while, you will never want to switch back to VS...

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Rider is great, but not everything you do in VS you do in Rider.

Comment: @BWA yes - i swear much less, for example

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I know, I'm using both. But not always Rider is good choice, but it's great tool.

Answer (score 7):

Nope, Visual Studio is not available for Linux.

There are some alternatives:

1. **Visual Studio Code**: lightweight version of VS, it works pretty well, it is fast and can be personalized a lot through extensions. It is not as powerful as Visual Studio, but it is a good approximation **and it is free**.
2. **Rider**: substitute of Visual Studio from the same company that made ReSharper. Pretty similar to VS, with some more tricks on the sleeve. It misses some functionality that VS has, but, in the overall, it is pretty good! It is not free tho: it costs 139$ for the first year (the following years are a bit cheaper).
3. **Virtual Machine + Windows + Visual Studio**. This is the option if you really cannot do without VS. Of course part of your machine's resources will be used for running the VM so the overall experience will be slower, but if you really need VS this is a good way to achieve it.

Please **do NOT run it with wine**. It is just not gonna work. The VM option is way easier and will work better.

Comment: Rider come with a cost of $139.00/year, not costly though

Comment: @ErwinDraconis surely it is more expensive than VSC, Visual Studio and Mono (that are free). But you're right, it depends a lot on the context (it'd be very costly for an independent developer of a 3rd world country, but not that bad for a 1st world dev, especially if it gets paid by the company they work for :p). I'll update my answer.

Comment: @ErwinDraconis and, I forgot to say, it is WAY cheaper than Visual Studio Professional and Enterprise. So compared to those it is not costly at all.

Comment: yes right , but i still prefer VS :)

Comment: @ErwinDraconis me too :p

Comment: Visual Studio Community does not have intelliSense, etc. And if you buy the enterprise version, it is a lot more costly than Rider. Beside, I often found VS complaining for errors even in Enterprise despite there were no errors. Just my esperience.